# ListView Binding to List of Custom class containing Dictionnary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, dictionary

I am learning WPF and I am trying to fill a ListView with a list of folders (as ListView Groups) and files for each folder(as ListView Items).

Using [WPF/MVVM Quick Start Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial) , I created the following classes (Business removed)

```
public class PatchGen
{
    public PatchGen() { }

    private string _folderName;
    private Dictionary<string, string> _filesInfo = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public string FolderName
    {
        get { return _folderName; }
        set { _folderName= value; }
    }
    public Dictionary<string, string> FilesInfo
    {
        get { return _filesInfo; }
        set { _filesInfo = value; }
    }
}
```

and the ViewModel:

```
public class PatchGenViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public PatchGenViewModel()
    {
    }

    List<PatchGen> _folderList = new List<PatchGen>();

    public List<PatchGen> Folders
    {
        get
        {
            return _folderList;
        }
        set { }
    }

    void AddFilesExecute()
    {
        //business here
    }

    bool CanAddFilesExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public ICommand AddFiles { get { return new RelayCommand(AddFilesExecute, CanAddFilesExecute); } }
```

The xaml section includes the `DataContext`and the `CollectionViewSource`:

```
<Window.DataContext>
  <local:PatchGenViewModel></local:PatchGenViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
  <CollectionViewSource x:Key='groups'
                        Source="{Binding Path=Folders}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
      <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="FolderName" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
  </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
```

and the ListView:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          Name="lstViewServices"
          ItemsSource='{Binding Source={StaticResource groups}}'>
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="File Name"
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=??? }"
                      Width="100" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="File Path"
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=??? }"
                      Width="Auto" />
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The ListView Group is not showing the Folders Names. ?

How to have the `File Name` and the `File Path` that represents the `FilesInfo` (Dictionnary < string,string > ) information displayed?

Is there any way to do this through XAML and ViewModel Class without the Code behind of the Xaml file?

Comment: Maybe it's because the Folder list is empty when the CollectionViewSource retrieve its value. If your collection is changing, you should consider implementing INotifyPropertyChanged (if you are reassigning it each time) or using ObservableCollection

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you want it to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just bind the File name to the File to the folder name property.

For the File Path, you need to bind it to the FilesInfo property. Why is it a dictionary? I guess I didn't understand why you are using a dictionary here? Maybe I am missing something but you should drop the dictionary and create your own little object.

```
public class FileInfo
{
    public string FileName {get;set;}
    public string FilePath {get;set;}
}
```

Then of course change your PatchGen object to use that instead of a Dictionary.

Maybe a screenshot of what you want it to look like would help. However, if you look at your XAML, you don't have anywhere to put your FolderName. You only have places for FileName and FilePath.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          Name="lstViewServices"
          ItemsSource='{Binding Source={StaticResource groups}}'>
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="File Name"
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FileName }"
                      Width="100" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="File Path"
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FilePath}"
                      Width="Auto" />
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

So you should add a place for FolderName. You have two lists it seems: the folder list and for each folder a the file list. But your view only has one level.

Here is an example that has two levels.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource='{Binding Folders}'>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding FolderName}" />
        <ListView Grid.Row="1"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Name="lstViewServices"
                  ItemsSource="FileInfo">
          <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
              <GridViewColumn Header="File Name"
                              DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FolderName}"
                              Width="100" />
              <GridViewColumn Header="File Path"
                              DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FolderName }"
                              Width="Auto" />
            </GridView>
          </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thank you @Rhyous, I was just trying to know if there was a way to bind this kind of object. It seems not.